# how to use subprocess.check_output() in Python to list any file name as "abc*"

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have couple of file with same name, and I wanted to get the latest file

[root@xxx tmp]# ls -t1 abclog*

abclog.1957
abclog.1830
abclog.1799
abclog.1742

I can accomplish that by executing below command.

[root@xxx tmp]# ls -t1  abclog*| head -n 1

abclog.1957

But when I am trying to execute the same in python , getting error :

> > > subprocess.check_output("ls -t1 abclog* | head -n 1",shell=True)
> > >       ls: cannot access abclog*: No such file or directory
> > >       ''

Seems it does not able to recognize '*' as a special parameter. How can I achieve the same ?

Comment: That code should work, assuming you are in the same directory as the ablog* directory. Make sure you are executing the script in the same place where you have abclog* files.

Comment: Thanks @jnvilo its working.. !

Comment: Rather than using a subprocess for this, you could also use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module in the Python standard library. This would be easier and probably more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others noted, your code should work. It doesn't work probably because the current directory isn't the one you suppose it is, so `abc*` is *not* expanded by the shell (even if `shell=True` is set), and passed as-is to `ls`, resulting in a "no such file" error.

You have to pass the absolute path or use `cwd=` parameter when calling `check_output`. Another nice pythonic alternative would be to avoid `subprocess`, and return the most recently modified file using only python code:

```
most_recent = max(glob.glob(os.path.join("path/to/file","abclog*"),key=os.path.getmtime)
```

(using `max` with `os.path.getmtime` as key and `glob.glob` to filter the files)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you execute this in the directory where the files exist. If you just fire up Idle to run this code, you will *not* be in that directory.

Comment: it's probably the issue here. since files are not found, '*' is passed unexpanded to `ls`